# How to apply the SSH key personal access to github via TortoiseGIT on Windows?

Tags: windows, github, ssh-keys, git-push, git-clone

I usually code on Windows for Linux and Windows machines, so I have to use Windows based tools to do my day to day workflow. Since GitHub removed the `user/pass` authentication and adapted `SSH` key, how can one change the personal workflow to apply new change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of making a video of the whole process for the people who have such transition.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDQZx-nF2UE